# Multiple instances of R produce equal imputations with MICE - random seed issue?

Tags: r, random-seed, r-mice

The multiple imputation packge `mice` uses a random number generator which can be set using the `set.seed` argument. I am running multiple instances of R (i.e. 3) in which the same data are imputed with the same `mice` arguments, where `set.seed=NA` which does not specify any seed value.

The three instances of R, however, produce exactly the SAME imputations. I am puzzled by this observation because I thought different instances of R should use different seed values when using `set.seed=NA`, but it appears they use the same. When I set `set.seed` manually, different imputations are produced.

My question is: is this plausible or may there be a computer (PC windows 7) problem that causes the seeds to be the same, even though I set `set.seed=NA`. I would welcome any thoughts on this problem.

By the way: I use multiple instances of R because the MICE function `ibind()` can be used to combine `mids` (multiply imputed data sets) objects. So it saves computing time on systems with multiple cores. This is of course nonsense if the same imputations are produced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `NULL` as an argument for `set.seed`, the RNG will produce different results.

```
> set.seed(NULL)
> rnorm(5)
[1] -0.45861478 -0.56525262 -0.95349202  0.05073898 -1.01956671
> set.seed(NULL)
> rnorm(5)
[1]  0.57787302  3.27165390  0.53466909 -1.15390604 -0.02624054
```

I recommend using the sequence

```
set.seed(NULL)
mice(...) # without seed argument
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that in MICE. Is you answer supposed to solve the problem in MICE as well or is more like a general remark about `set.seed`?

Comment: @tomka See the update. This is more a general remark. Unfortunately, you can specify `seed = NULL` in `mice`.

Comment: It works to produce different imputes, Sven - thank you! What I do not yet understand is why different instances of R produce the same imputes, do they use the same `seed` value if I do not `set.seed(NULL)`?

Comment: @tomka I cannot reproduce this outcome. On my machine (OS X), different instances of R start with different `seed` and hence produce different results.

Comment: I am confused about this observation as well: apparently sometimes it works without using set.seed(NULL), sometimes not, I cannot pin down what's the cause.

Comment: I will except this as the answer, because it appears to produce proper imputes.